# Type in abstract class constructor can't be inferred using KClass<>

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, generics

I am trying to make an abstract base fragment and to initialize the view in it.

```
abstract class BaseFrag<V: View>(private val clazz: KClass<V>) : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? =
            clazz.constructors.firstOrNull()?.call(context)
}
```

This is how I can initialize a fragment with that: `class HomeFrag : BaseFrag<HomeView>(HomeView::class)`

Is there any way to make HomeView inferred and type `class HomeFrag : BaseFrag(HomeView::class)` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this approach using `out` modifier:

```
abstract class BaseFrag(private val clazz: KClass<out View>) : Fragment() { ... }

class HomeFrag : BaseFrag(HomeView::class)
```

Comment: Your answer is correct and awesome, I completely forgot about out. The only problem I have is that I'm using V later on like: `lateinit var layout: V`. Any idea if it's possible?

Comment: If you use generic parameter, you should specify it when creating a subclass: `class HomeFrag : BaseFrag<HomeView>(HomeView::class)`

Answer (score 2):

I have tried several ways to achieve this result but I have not succeeded. It is probably still impossible.

https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/infer-abstract-class-type-from-constructor/1913